# input box datepicker not working in all pages of jQuery DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, datepicker, datatables

I have jsp page having jQuery DataTables which contain more then 20 pages I'm using textbox in datatable `td` tags which shows datepicker i.e. check-in /check-out date.

On the 1st page its works perfectly but on the other pages datepicker class is not apply. Here is following code which I used.

HTML code

```
<table id="tableBookingByBooker">
    <thead class="btn-default">
        <tr>
            <th>checkInDate</th>
            <th>checkInDate</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input id="checkInDate${data[0]}" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="Text1" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JS Code:

```
$('input[id^=checkInDate]').each(function (index, element) {
    var checkOutDate = (new Date($('#checkOutDate' + $(this).attr('id').substring(11)).val()));
    checkOutDate.setDate(checkOutDate.getDate() - 1);
    $(this).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
        maxDate: checkOutDate,
    });
});

$('input[id^=checkOutDate]').each(function (index, element) {
    var checkInDate = (new Date($('#checkInDate' + $(this).attr('id').substring(12)).val()));
    checkInDate.setDate(checkInDate.getDate() + 1);
    $(this).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
        minDate: checkInDate,
    });
});
```

Input box (checkIn/checkout) Datepicker is successfully working in 1st page of datatable but other pages datepicker is not working.

I tried the pagination event and put js code in the function click but it did not work properly

Comment: My guess would be that you need to instantiate the date-pickers on page change (assuming they are getting unique ID's)

Comment: PUT CHECK-IN /CHECK-OUT CODE ABOVE DATA TABLE JS CODE....ITS WORK PROPERLY

Comment: Did you get this solved then? Want to accept an answer or close the question if it was something else entirely?

Comment: yes @maleki as per my question you answer is perfect here i suggest that any code which going to apply on data-table must be put before datatable js code.
Thank you.

Comment: @RaviPrajapati I'm glad I could be of help. I think it might have been a language barrier issue that gave me a different impression. Normally if your issue is solved by someone or yourself, you click the check-mark next to an answer to indicate your acceptance of an answer. This helps others coming across the question know where to look first.

Comment: @RaviPrajapati It also gives incentive to answer your questions in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ted pointed out, your best bet is to register an on "page change" event. The problem is that a one-time initialization using jquery select won't have an affect on dynamically loaded content.

There might be other ways, but the one referenced by dataTables looks like this.

https://datatables.net/reference/event/page

```
//Your Check-in UI DatePicker code.
var checkInInit = function () {}
//Your Check-out UI DatePicker code.
var checkOutInit = function () {}

var table = $('#dataTable').DataTable();
$('#dataTable').on('page.dt', function () {
    checkInInit();
    checkOutInit();
});
```

Comment: `on('page.dt')` didn't work for me but `on('draw.dt')` did, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32133849/datepicker-not-triggered-on-next-page-datatable

Answer (score 0):

Yes function call successfully but the applied code checkIn/checkOut date picker is not working i have given unique name of each checkInDate and checkOut Date Elements.
    Here i applied following code...

```
// Check-in UI DatePicker code.
    var checkInInit = function () {
        alert('call');
        $('input[id^=checkInDate]').each(function(index, element) {
            var checkOutDate = (new Date($('#checkOutDate'+$(this).attr('id').substring(11)).val()));
            checkOutDate.setDate(checkOutDate.getDate() - 1);
            $(this).datepicker({
                dateFormat:'mm/dd/yy',
                maxDate : checkOutDate,
            });
        });

    }
    // Check-out UI DatePicker code.
    var checkOutInit = function () {
        alert('call');
        $('input[id^=checkOutDate]').each(function(index, element) {
            var checkInDate =(new Date( $('#checkInDate'+$(this).attr('id').substring(12)).val()));
            checkInDate.setDate(checkInDate.getDate() + 1);
                $(this).datepicker({
                dateFormat:'mm/dd/yy',
                minDate : checkInDate,
        });
    });
    }
    $('#tableBookingByBooker').on('page.dt', function () {
        checkInInit();
        checkOutInit();
    });
```

Comment: Here function called but datepiker not applied on text box. i think issue in function call. alert com before datatable page is appear...
Is there any solution that function called after datatable page is appeared ?