# Datepicker not triggered on next page Datatable

Tags: jquery, datatable, bootstrap-modal

I just want to ask how can datetimepicker be triggered on the next page of a data table? It is working correctly in the first page as seen in this screenshot. 
[image]

But when I go now to the next page, the calendar is not triggered anymore:

[image]

Some suggested to re-initialize which I added like this:

```
var table = $('#ot_dataTables').DataTable();

$('#ot_dataTables').on( 'page.dt', function () {    
    $('#ot_dataTables').dataTable({
            order: [[ 0, "desc" ],[ 2, "desc" ]]
        });
} );
```

But still the calendar is not showing. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Have you checked your `console` for the `errors` when you `trigger` `datetimepicker` in second `pop-up`. May be there's some problem regarding `jQuery` or something else.

Comment: Hi @vivekkupadhyay, Thanks but no error in the console when I click the second pop-up. :(

Comment: Check console when you `click` to `trigger` the `datetimepicker`. It seems you're using `bootstrap` `datetimepicker` and this popup which you're triggering is this a `modal-box` or `iframe` ?

Comment: Hi @vivekkupadhyay, Yes I am using a bootstrap datetimepicker. And it is modal-dialog.

Comment: do you have any demo **URL** or [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net) as its difficult to give the solution, and guessing is not the right way :P

Comment: Sorry, but I have not setup one.

Answer (score 1):

So this is similar to Senjuti's answer, but I wanted to post mine because I was able to do it without the need of recreating the table instance. However, she is right that a listener on `page.dt` won't work in this case but a listener on `draw.dt` will.

In my answer, I'll use your table as an example and assume that `input` tags in the table have the class name `date-field`. What worked for me was recalling `datepicker()` on the input tags like so,

```
var table = $('#ot_dataTables').DataTable();
$('#ot_dataTables').on('draw.dt', function () { 
    $(".date-field").datepicker();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me. I put my code below as there were some other requirements with the datetimepicker. Hope that can also help other people.

Answer (score 0):

I know its late but for others might facing this issue, use `draw.dt` instead of `page.dt`. Whenever the datatable is drawn, the event fires.

```
var table = $('#ot_dataTables').DataTable();

$('#ot_dataTables').on( 'draw.dt', function () {    
    $('#ot_dataTables').dataTable({
        order: [[ 0, "desc" ],[ 2, "desc" ]]
    });
});
```

**page.dt** - Page change event - fired when the table's paging is updated.

**draw.dt** - Draw event - fired once the table has completed a draw.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem for the datetimepicker in the datatable. I added one code snippet to fix the issue. Here I have added details below:

HTML code:

```html
<table id="list" class="table table-hover  table-bordered">
.......    
    <div class='input-group date' id='input_date'>
<input  onkeydown="return false" type='text' class="form-control" />
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
..........
</table>
```

I already had the code for the datetimpicker like the following(before adding datatable):

```
       //This is the code for bootstrap datetimepicker
       $("div#input_date").datetimepicker({
            format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm',
        }).on('dp.show', function () {
            return $(this).data('DateTimePicker').minDate(new Date());
        });
```

I added another code snippet so that it works same on the next page of pagination.

Following code I added for fixing the datetime picker not appearing on the next pages of Pagination

```
       //code for datatable
       $('#list').DataTable({
            "bSort" : false //this is for disabling datable sorting
        });
//to fix the issue: datetimepicker not appearing in datatable when moved to next page(for pagination) 
      $('#list').on( 'draw.dt', function () {
            $("div#input_date").datetimepicker({
                format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm',
                minDate:new Date()
            })
        });
```